# Mac Sierra - find when something was deleted

Tags: messages, macos, logs

My boss logged into my computer and deleted a series of text messages between us regarding my being injured at work.  I have been able to recover the messages on my phone but I was wondering is there a way to see when those messages were deleted from my computer because it had to happen when I wasn’t there.  I could then show he deleted them.

Comment: So, this can probably be found, but I would suggest you find an IT specialist (independent, hopefully "rated" by police or equivalent) to do this so that the evidence is clear and no suggestion of you "creating" it can be entertained.

Comment: You also want to raise this with HR. If your boss did that, it's probably a sackable offence.